# Why is my Rails app sometimes routing incorrectly only in DEV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Sometimes when I log out, I get this error. It only happens in DEV. I suspect it might have to do with Turbolinks, but I'm not sure.

```
Started GET "/users/logout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-11 20:08:31 -0400
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"logout"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "logout"]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with id=logout):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:11:in `show'
```

I don't even have a GET route for that path. It should have given me a route error.

```
  resources :users do
    collection do
      get 'login', to: :login
      post 'login', to: :loginCreate 
      post 'logout', to: :logout
```

`rake routes`

```
      logout_users POST   /users/logout(.:format)                                              users#logout
```

Haml

```
  .button=link_to 'Logout', logout_users_path, method: 'post'
```

The problem goes away when I reload. JS is enabled.

Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is most likely a route for /users/:id and that is why it is outputting "logout" as the id param when it is a GET request:

Parameters: {"id"=>"logout"}

As to why your link is a GET and not a POST I am not really familiar with HAML. From your code example it looks like its trying to specify the link be a POST? If so, I have never seen that before on an anchor tag.

Comment: The Haml is similar to the ERB `<%= link_to 'Logout', logout_users_path, method: 'post' %>`

Answer (score 1):

You should move the logout/login logic in a different controller, i.e. sessions_controller and then have sessions/login sessions/logout, and not nest those actions within a users action.

Because your route file is matching users/logout to update users/:id with id=logout and that is why you are seeing the error you see.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're calling `resources :users` which [creates the `show`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) record like this:

```
/users/:id
```

Because this is being created *before* your other routes, Rails will be processing it first, hence if you send `/logout` it's getting confused. An immediate fix (using a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)):

```
#config/routes.rb
scope "/users" do
  get 'login', to: "users#login"
  post 'login', to: "users#loginCreate"
  post 'logout', to: "users#logout"
end
resources :users
```

I would also recommend using the `SessionsController` approach as mentioned by Marc in his answer. [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) & other authentication systems use this